# UseReducer modifying state multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I assume this is because of an anti-pattern side-effect. I get keyboard input from the user and use it to modify the state. I recently switched to useReducer from useState hooks because of a growing complex state. It worked great with useState hooks. Every keyboard input is printed to the screen multiple times. But none keyboard modification to the state (changes to state not from event handler), does not show multiple renders.

Here is my code:

```
function TextBox() {
    const AppState = {
        /// Manages the state of the lines on the screen
        line: [[]],
        /// Line Index...
        lIdx: 0,
        /// Word Index...
        wIdx: 0,

        caretOn: false, timerOn: true, wordWrap: true,
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(modifier, AppState)
    /*
     ...

    */
    return (
        <div id="txtbox" 
            tabIndex="0" 
            ref = {txtBoxRef}
            onKeyDown={(e) => dispatch({type: e.key})} >
                <Lines linesProp={linesParam} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function modifier(state, action)
{
    try {
        /// Stops the caret from blinking...
        const caretState = {
            caretOn: true, timerOn: false, wordWrap: true,
        }

        let values = {
                newLine: [], newLIdx: 0, newWIdx: 0
        }

        const set = val => ({...state, ...caretState, line: val.newLine, 
                lIdx: val.newLIdx, wIdx: val.newWIdx})

        switch (action.type)
        {
            case "Backspace":
             // Calls the Function that handles backspaces 
                // Declare new state values...
                values = Backspace({   /// Modify state values...
                    line: state.line, lIdx: state.lIdx, wIdx: state.wIdx
                })
                /// Update state values...
                return set(values)
            case " ":
            // Calls the fucntion that handles input from the spacebar
                /// Modify state values...
                values = spaceBar({line: state.line, lIdx: state.lIdx, wIdx: state.wIdx})
                /// Update state values...
                return set(values)
            /* .... */
           case "ArrowDown":
                if (state.lIdx < state.line.length)
                    return { ...state, ...caretState, lIdx: state.lIdx + 1}
                break;
            case "Enter":
                values = handleEnterKey({line: state.line, lIdx: state.lIdx, wIdx: state.wIdx})
                return set(values)
            case "text_wrap":
                values = handleWrap ({line: state.line, lIdx: state.lIdx, wIdx: state.wIdx,
                wordWrap: state.wordWrap})
                return {...state, ...values}
            case "hide-caret":
                return {...state, caretOn: state.caretOn=false};
            case "show-caret":
                return {...state, caretOn: state.caretOn=true};
            case "set-timer-on":
                return {...state, timerOn: state.timerOn=true};
            default:
            /// Modify state values...
                values = updateLine(action.type, state.line, state.lIdx, state.wIdx)
                /// Update state values...
                return set(values)
            }
            
    }
        catch (e) {
        console.info(e)
        console.log(state)
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than the `show|hide-caret` actions mutating previous state (i.e. `caretOn: state.caretOn = false` and `caretOn: state.caretOn = true` I don't see any other obvious mutations/side-effects, but we can't see what any of your utility functions are doing. Can you include `Backspace`, `spaceBar`, `handleEnterKey`, `handleWrap`, `updateLine`, etc.... functions?

Comment: @DrewReese, Sure here are the source files:

[TextBox](https://github.com/Dan6200/text_box/blob/main/src/TextBox.js),   
[Reducer](https://github.com/Dan6200/text_box/blob/main/src/KeyFunctions.js),  
[Utilities](https://github.com/Dan6200/text_box/blob/main/src/utilities.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the technical knowledge, but it seems react does not want any side-effects at all with `<React.StrictMode>`. If you have a non-primitive data type. useReducer would not deep check and see it is the same object. Avoid mutating objects, deep copy and return the updated objects. This is similar to setState. useState handles mutating objects better.

Fix: I rewrote all methods to be immutable.